# How to prevent "sms sending"/texting on android?

Tags: android, sms

I want to prevent "sms sending"/texting on android.

There are some applications doing that but i don't know how?

eg.:

- [Textecution](http://www.textecution.com/)
- [Stop Drunk Text 2.0](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/apps/app/com.drunkapp2/Stop-Drunk-Texts-2-0/)

Answer (score 2):

Stop Drunk Text 2.0, as far as I can see, works by messing up the contacts you choose to prevent texting to.

About Textecution - I could't get enough information about its mechanism but I guess that it blocks running the Texting application somehow, not actually sending messages. Maybe one could tell more about it if he saw the app in action, which I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you have accepted them to have the permission to send sms you will have to stick with that UNLESS you download Droid Wall (my choice) and you choose to block internet/phone network access to those applications.

Remember, Droid Wall. It's free in the Market. You'd have your phone rooted in order to let it work by the way.